# Query = Unknown system variable 'c3'

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use both `REPLACE` and `SET`in a query, whithout any succes!

Error message:

`Unknown system variable 'c3'`

What am i doing wrong?

**PHP**

```
 $query = "SET NEW.c3 = CONCAT(OLD.c3, NEW.:c3);
           REPLACE INTO table(
                c1,
                c2,
                c3)
           VALUES(
                :c1,
                :c2,
                :c3)";
$query_params = array(
                ':c1' => $c1,
                ':c2' => $c2,
                ':c3' => $c3);
```

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES` - what does this show? Probably not 'c3'

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Daan How do i use `Show variables;`? A quick look at mysql shows: mysql> SHOW VARIABLES; But "Netbeans" won't alow this a correct code. If i use it like that i get: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`

Comment: @axiac I need to replace c1 & c2 with new data from variable. But in case c3, i'd like to CONCAT the new data whith the old one? I'm trying to use both `REPLACE` and `SET` in one query.

Comment: @Wrikken I still got: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: `REPLACE` is a shortcut for `DELETE` (if exists) followed by `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you want to insert a new row or update the existing one (if it already exists in the table). If this is the case then the correct query is:

```
INSERT INTO table(c1, c2, c3) VALUES
    (:c1, :c2, :c3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    c3 = CONCAT(c3, :c3);
```

or, if you want to insert/update many rows at once:

```
INSERT INTO table(c1, c2, c3) VALUES
    (:c1, :c2, :c3),
    (:d1, :d2, :d3),
    (:e1, :e2, :e3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    c3 = CONCAT(c3, VALUES(c3));
```

Comment: This is almost what i want. I need C1 & C2 to INSERT OR if excist UPDATE. But with C3 i need INSERT or CONCAT if excist.

Comment: `... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c1 = VALUES(c1), c2 = VALUES(c2), c3 = CONCAT(c3, VALUES(c3))`.

Comment: Then, is it better to use REPLACE instead of INSERT, this will give me a smaller code?

Comment: **No.** `REPLACE` does not update your existing row. `REPLACE` deletes it then inserts a new one and there is no way to tell it to use something from the row it deletes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html